# ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore usage question

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm playing around with ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore, yet it seems even in this basic usage I have some sort of bug/misunderstanding.

The (only once) awaited ValueTask does never complete.

If the call to `mre.SetResult` is done before awaiting the ValueTask it works as expected.

```
internal struct ManualResetValueTaskSource<T> : IValueTaskSource<T>
{
    private ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T> _taskSource = new();

    public short Version => _taskSource.Version;

    public ManualResetValueTaskSource()
    {
        _taskSource.RunContinuationsAsynchronously = true;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal ValueTask<T> GetTask() => new(this, _taskSource.Version);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal void SetResult(T result) => _taskSource.SetResult(result);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal void Reset() => _taskSource.Reset();

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public T GetResult(short token) => _taskSource.GetResult(token);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public ValueTaskSourceStatus GetStatus(short token) => _taskSource.GetStatus(token);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void OnCompleted(Action<object?> continuation, object? state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags) => _taskSource.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        var mre = new ManualResetValueTaskSource<int>();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(250);
            mre.SetResult(123);
        });

        var result = await mre.GetTask();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing value type in constructor here:

```
internal ValueTask<T> GetTask() => new(this, _taskSource.Version);
```

After this you capture value type local variable in closure here:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(250);
    mre.SetResult(123);
});
```

That means you are completing copy of `mre` inside anonymous function. If you change `ManualResetValueTaskSource` to `class` code works.